# Building android_core. android_acm_serial:debug failed

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have some problems building android_core.
I execute:

```
roscd android_core
./gradlew debug
```

And I have this:

```
:android_acm_serial:debug
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_acm_serial:debug'.
> Command 'ant' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.
```

I have executed this before, but it does not work.

```
 roscd google
./gradlew install
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39625/building-android_core.-android_acm_serial:debug-failed/) by [JMata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2907/jmata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2012-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I got the same error and I resolved it using the answer from this Question:
http://answers.ros.org/question/33104/error-building-android-core2/

Basically what you need to do is tell android to make a build.xml for the project that is missing the file.
cd into the Folder that is missing the build.xml and then

```
android list targets
```

pick one that is recent enough, for me it was target 4 (Android 4.0), so i ran the following command then:

```
android update project --target 4 --path .
```

if you build the whole android_core then you might need to do it again for each project that is missing the build.xml.
Hope that helped.

---

Originally posted by [Bernd Kampl](https://answers.ros.org/users/3118/bernd-kampl/) with karma: 76 on 2012-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0